# What causes ERROR 000732 from MosaicToNewRaster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, raster, error-000732

I'm trying to run the MosaicToNewRaster tool as part of a python script. This is my code:

```
input_rasters = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5), arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6), arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7), arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)
output_location = "C:/Birkbeck_Python/Prog_Assign_1.gdb"
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(input_rasters, output_location, "R_Dataset", "", "",    "", "1", "", "")
```

I get the following error message, anybody got any ideas? It works fine when I hardcode it.

Thanks

ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Rasters: Dataset '';'';'';'' does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (MosaicToNewRaster).

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a raster list rather than a series of paths separated by commas.  Try something like the following:

```
input_rasters = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output_location = "C:/Birkbeck_Python/Prog_Assign_1.gdb"
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(input_rasters, output_location, "R_Dataset", "", "",    "", "1", "", "")
```

Then you can add a multivalue raster dataset when you produce the script tool, as follows:

[image]

Comment: THanks @Aaron, I tried what you said but now it's saying: 'ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000735: Input Rasters: Value is required
Failed to execute (MosaicToNewRaster).' Any ideas?

Comment: From the help page @Luke linked to: "The input raster datasets are all the raster datasets you would like to mosaic together. The inputs must have the same number of bands and same bit depth; otherwise, the tool will exit with an error message."

Comment: I'm 100% sure they're all the same depth etc. I can get it to work perfectly when I hardcode everthing! It's just not recognising the rasters in the workspace!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a [semicolon separated string](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000098000000) instead of a list/tuple.

```
input_rasters = ';'.join((arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5), arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6), arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7), arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)))
output_location = "C:/Birkbeck_Python/Prog_Assign_1.gdb"
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(input_rasters, output_location, "R_Dataset", "", "",    "", "1", "", "")
```

Comment: Thanks, after I change it to the above do I use multivalue rasters in my script tool?

Comment: I tried the above with a multivalue raster input and it gave me the same error as I was getting: 'ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000735: Input Rasters: Value is required
Failed to execute (MosaicToNewRaster).' Any advice appreciated.

Comment: @Dunuts: no, if you use a multivalue parameter, arcpy.GetParameterAsText(parameter number) will return a  semicolon separated string